# Collecting users' data as an array

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I want to collect my users' data as an array:

```
h = {}
a = [["user_3", 765], ["user_1", 2], ["user_1", 1], ["user_2", 124],["user_1", 3], ["user_2", 223], ["user_2", 334]]
# Expected output :: {"user_3"=>[765], "user_1"=>[2, 1, 3], "user_2"=>[124, 223, 334]} 
a.each do |x|
  if h.keys.include?(x.first)
    h[x.first] = (h[x.first] << x.last)
  else
    h[x.first] = [x.last]
  end
end
```

Everything is working fine in my Ruby script, but is there any better way to achieve my result?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/enumerable/map_by.rb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You very rarely need to modify a variable from inside an `each` block.

Instead, check out all the methods available to you in [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) and [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html).

Among them, there's `#each_with_objects`, which you can use like so:

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |(name, id), hash|
  hash[name] ||= []
  hash[name] << id
end
```

which'll produce the same hash as your current code.

You could also do:

```
a.group_by(&:first).map do |name, pairs|
  [name, pairs.map(&:last)]
end
```

That returns an array of arrays, but you can turn that into a `Hash` with `Hash[]`. You may not need to, though. A lot of things treat an `Array` object with `[key, value]`-style elements the same as a `Hash` object. Depends on your needs.

Comment: For the first, you could also use `Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }` in place of `{}` and get rid of the `hash[name] ||= []`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes True. However, the danger is that the hash then _always_ creates and returns an empty array, if you access a non-existent key. This could be confusing if you afterward expect `result["user_5"]` to be `nil`, because you'll get an empty array instead. And if you afterward check `result.keys` you'll also see a `"user_5"` key in there. In other words, you can't quite rely on the hash telling you if a user is present in it or not - at least not in the usual way of `nil == false`.

Comment: Thank you very much. need bit more explanation for you answers. it will really me.

Comment: Flambino, re @QPaysTaxes suggestion, isn't there a lesson here: to determine if a hash `h` has a key `k`, one should always use `h.key?(k)` (or `h.has_key?(k)` or `h.include?(k)`), rather than `h[k]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland There is -- `h.key?(k)`. However, this is not to check. This is to set, if it hasn't been already.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, please note [Hash#key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F).

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, I mean this code above, not `h.key?`. `h[k] ||= []` sets `h[k]` to `[]` if it wasn't already  set.

Comment: Ah, I was referring to Flambino's reply to your first comment; that is, I don't see a problem using a default array as you suggested if one always uses `h.key?(k)` to determine if a hash has a particular key. fwiw, `||=[]` tends to be a bit faster than using a default array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Using `key?` and its ilk is certainly safer and sidesteps any pitfalls here. Still, if this was wrapped in a method and part of some API, I wouldn't _expect_ that method to return anything except a plain `Hash`. Docs could make that clear of course, but "principle of least surprise" and all that. Besides, I'm not a huge fan of how it, in this case, creates empty arrays for missing keys, when the expectation (that word again) would be a hash of only non-empty arrays. So my preference is to stick to `||=`, though either thing's valid.

Answer (score 1):

Another way uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |(name,id),h|
  h.update(name=>[id]) { |_,oid,nid| oid.concat(nid) }
end
  #=> {"user_3"=>[765], "user_1"=>[2, 1, 3], "user_2"=>[124, 223, 334]}
```

Let's see what's happening here:

```
e = a.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["user_3", 765], ["user_1", 2], ["user_1", 1],
  #                  ["user_2", 124], ["user_1", 3], ["user_2", 223],
  #                  ["user_2", 334]]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first element of `e` is passed to `each_with_object`'s block and the block calculation is performed:

```
(name,id),h = e.next
     #=> [["user_3", 765], {}] 
name #=> "user_3" 
id   #=> 765 
h    #=> {} 
h.update(name=>[id])
     #=> {}.update("user_3"=>[765]) 
     #=> {"user_3"=>[765]}
```

`update`'s block is not used here because the key `"user_3"` is not present in `h`. The next value of the enumerator is now passed to the block:

```
(name,id),h = e.next
  #=> [["user_1", 2], {"user_3"=>[765]}] 
h.update(name=>[id])
  #=> {"user_3"=>[765]}.update("user_1"=>[2])
  #=> {"user_3"=>[765], "user_1"=>[2]}
```

Again, the block is not used because `h` does not have a key `"user_1"`. The third element of `e` is passed to the block:

```
(name,id),h = e.next
  #=> [["user_1", 1], {"user_3"=>[765], "user_1"=>[2]}] 
h.update(name=>[id])
  #=> {"user_3"=>[765], "user_1"=>[2]}.update("user_1"=>[1])
```

This time, both hashes being merged have the key `"user_1"`, so the block is called up to determine the value of that key:

```
{ |key,oid,nid| oid.concat(nid) }
  #=> { |"user_1",[2],[1]| [2].concat([1]) }
  #=> [2,1]
```

so now:

```
h #=> {"user_3"=>[765], "user_1"=>[2, 1]}
```

I have drawn attention to the fact that the argument `key` was not used in this block calculation by replacing that variable with an underscore (which is indeed a variable). Some Rubiests might write `_key` instead.

The remaining calculations are similar.